# Instance variable access in subclasses

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I am hoping that someone could shed some light on the error that I am receiving below. I define an instance variable in the parent class `Node` and want to access and modify it in the subclass `AddSubNode`, whenever I try to access `@code` I receive this error:

```
'code': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I must be misunderstanding Ruby's inheritance model, but I thought that I could do this.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :code

  def initialize
    @code = []
  end
end

class AddSubNode < Node
  def initialize op, l, r
    @op = op
    @l  = l
    @r  = r
  end

  def code
    @code << 1 # error: `code': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    @code
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@l} #{@op} #{@right}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the super initializer in the initializer of the subclass.

```
class AddSubNode < Node
  def initialize op, l, r
    super()
    @op = op
    @l  = l
    @r  = r
  end
...
```

edit: forgot parenthesis

Comment: interesting, for some reason I had assumed that this was done implicitly. Thanks!

Comment: No, methods in Ruby don't implicitly call their superclass implementation. That wouldn't make sense, and no other language does it, either. May I ask *why* you assumed that?

Comment: @JörgWMittag It seems like a desirable feature to me, in this particular scenario I have ~100 subclasses of `Node`, I had to go back in each one of them and add `super()`. Could you give a reason why it wouldn't make sense for this to happen implicitly?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: There are three methods in your `AddSubNode` class. But you only want that behavior in one of them; in fact, in `code` it would even raise a `NoMethodError`. So, if automatically calling `super()` were the default behavior, then you would have to explicitly turn it off in two thirds of your methods (and in a *real* class with maybe a dozen methods, the ratio would probably be much higher). Besides, why `super()`, i.e. suppressing all the arguments? Why not `super` passing along all the arguments? And when do you call it? At the beginning, the middle, the end?

Comment: In this case super needs to be called with `super()`, not passing any arguments. Otherwise the superclass initializer would give you an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0)`. The location of the super call does not matter in this case. However, I tend to place it at the top for visibility reasons if I have the choice.

Answer (score 2):

When you redefine the `initialize` method in the subclass, you overwrite the original. Hence the instance variable `@code` is never initialized, and you code throws an error when you call `@code << 1`.

Calling `super()` from the `initialize` method in your subclass (effectively calling it's parent) or utilizing `@code << 1 unless @code.nil?` are a few ways to address the error.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen What don't you understand about it?

Comment: What rudolph means is that the subclass automatically inherits the super initializer (which is usually called). But with your `def initialize op, l, r` in the subclass, you overwrite it with a new implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here I just tried to give you some visualization to test such scenarios.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :code

  def initialize
    @code = []
  end
end

class AddSubNode < Node
  def initialize op, l, r
    @op = op
    @l  = l
    @r  = r
  end

  def code
    @code << 1 # error: `code': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    @code
  end

end

ob = AddSubNode.new(1,2,3)
p ob.instance_variables #=> [:@op, :@l, :@r]
p ob.instance_variable_defined?(:@code) #=> false
p ob.instance_variable_set :@code,[12] #=> [12]
p ob.instance_variable_defined?(:@code) #=> true
p ob.instance_variable_get :@code #=> [12]
p ob.instance_variables #=> [:@op, :@l, :@r, :@code]
p ob.code #=> [12, 1]
```